# Complex multirow/multicolumn table

Tags: latex, tabular, multirow

I am trying to create a complex table to define a lot of concepts, that can have subconcepts with their own definitions.

Right now, my problem is controlling the width of every column of the table. Because the definitions use more than one line and can get pretty long, LaTeX does not break the line like I'm used to do at normal tables. For that, I tend to use p{0.X\columnwidth} instead of l/c/r, but it doesn't seem to work here.

Right now, the goals to attain for this table are:

- Make it autofit content inside the cell in an automatic/semi-automatic way (i.e.: without manually doing a line break);
- Vertically and horizontally center every cell that is not a definition;
- Make the whole table fit inside a page.

Here is a small example already built:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{p{0.1\columnwidth}p{0.1\columnwidth}p{0.1\columnwidth}p{0.5\columnwidth}}
\hline
\multirow{11}{*}{A} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Definition of A}                        \\ \cline{2-4} 
                    & \multirow{5}{*}{A1} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Definition of A1} \\ \cline{3-4} 
                    &                     & A11        & Definition of A11       \\ \cline{3-4} 
                    &                     & A12        & Definition of A12       \\ \cline{3-4} 
                    &                     & A13        & Definition of A13       \\ \cline{3-4} 
                    &                     & A14        & Definition of A14       \\ \cline{2-4} 
                    & A2                  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Definition of A2} \\ \cline{2-4} 
                    & \multirow{4}{*}{A3} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Definition of A3} \\ \cline{3-4} 
                    &                     & A31        & Definition of A31       \\ \cline{3-4} 
                    &                     & A32        & Definition of A32       \\ \cline{3-4} 
                    &                     & A33        & Definition of A33       \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{B}  & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Definition of B}                        \\ \cline{2-4} 
                    & B1                  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Definition of B1} \\ \cline{2-4} 
                    & B2                  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Definition of B2} \\ \cline{2-4} 
                    & B3                  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Definition of B3} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{C}  & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Definition of C}                        \\ \cline{2-4} 
                    & C1                  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Definition of C1} \\ \cline{2-4} 
                    & C2                  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Definition of C1} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you specify in which a p column is not working? You table does not have any line breaks nor a p column.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm trying to declare in tabular. I've updated accordingly. The line breaks are not there as I would not want to fill the post with irrelevant text. Any big text of 3-4 paragraphs would work.

Comment: Your `\multicolumn`s with `l` as column specifier don't break the text. You need some `p{...}` specifier instead where you calculate the width. For example `\multicolumn{2}{p{0.6\columnwidth+2\tabcolsep}}{Definition of A1 more text ....}`. You need `\usepackage{calc}` for this to work. But using the package `tabulararray` might actually be better for this kind of table.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum I guess your comment helped something. Can you please take a look at it to see if I've applied it correctly? https://www.overleaf.com/7544793191fnrzkkzqnzzw Furthermore, how can I make the main words vertically and horizontally centered, since they are in a multirow display?

Comment: (1) The `\multirow`s must have `{=}` instead of `{*}` otherwise they will have no line breaks. (2) Some long words ate the beginning of a cell will not be broken unless you put `\hspace*{0pt}` in from of them. (3) the `\multicolumn{3}`s must have `4\tabcolsep` instead of 2. (4) To fit the table on the page, you may have to use `\small` or `\footnotesize`.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum You're right! Thanks for the help! Just one thing... how do I vertically center the names?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `multirow` can't deal well with this kind of table, because it doesn't get information of LaTeX's `tabular` about the heights of the table cells. So you would have to count the actual number of lines that the cells occupy, which is annoying.

This kind of table is much easier to do with the `tabularray` package, which has its own implementation of the table mechanism which does have this kind of information available. Actually it is possible to use most of your code by just replacing `\usepackage{tabular}` with `\usepackage{tabularray}` and the `tabular` environment with `tblr`. However, althoug the `\multirow`s will be properly positioned, you will not get the full power of `tabularray`, for example the entries will not be horizontally centered. Moreover, support for `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` in `tabularray` will disappear in a future version. So I rewrote it to use the syntax that `tabularray` has for these cases with `\SetCell`. A few remarks to begin with:

- In `tabular` you would use expressions like `0.7\textwidth+2\tabcolsep` to calculate the width of a `\multicolumn`. However, `tabularray` doesn't use `\tabcolsep`. Instead it has `leftsep` and `rightsep` parameters. These are available as `\leftsep` and `\rightsep` inside a cell, but unfortunately they are not set outside the cell, for example in a width specification. Therefor I (ab)used `\tabcolsep` in the width calculation, and set `colsep=\tabcolsep` which sets both `leftsep` and `rightsep`.
- `tabularray` uses `\raggedright` internally for `l` and `p` columns, but with the standard LaTeX definitions this makes hyphenation very difficult. Therefore I used the `ragged2e` package to get better definitions for this. It has to be included **before** `tabularray` to work properly.
- I defined commands `\Mdois` and `\Mtres` for the `\multicolumn{2}` and `{3}` cells. I included the `\justifying` command (from the `ragged2e` package) to get fully justified text. You can leave this out if you don't want the text to be justified.
- I included `cells={c,m}` to get the cells both horizontally and vertically centered by default. I also used `m{}` type column specifiers for vertical centering in the larger text columns.
- I used `rowsep=1pt` to get the rows closer to each other. Still I had to use `\small` to get everything fit on the page. Actually the table is sticking into the page footer, so you might have to use an even smaller font size, like `\footnotesize`.
- TeX doesn't hyphenate the first word of a paragraph, unless you include something like `\hspace{0pt}` before it. I made a macro `\HH` for this and put that before some large words like "Confidencialidade". You could actually put that in the column definition if you want.
- The texts that were originally in the `\multirow` or `\multicolumn` still have braces `{...}` around them although that is not longer necessary (they are not parameters of the `\SetCell`, `\Mdois` or `\Mtres`. I thought it was too much work to remove them and they don't harm.

So here is the solution. I reduced it to the minimum necessary for the table.

```
\documentclass[sigplan]{acmart}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[tbp]
\newcommand\HH{\hspace{0pt}}
\NewTableCommand{\Mdois}{\SetCell[c=2]{preto=\justifying,wd=0.7\textwidth+2\tabcolsep}}
\NewTableCommand{\Mtres}{\SetCell[c=3]{preto=\justifying,wd=0.8\textwidth+4\tabcolsep}}
\SetTblrInner{rowsep=1pt}
\small
\centering
\caption{Especificação das Métricas do CVSS}
\label{tab:metricas-cvss}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={ m{0.1\textwidth} m{0.1\textwidth} m{0.1\textwidth} Q[preto=\justifying,wd={0.6\textwidth}] },colsep=\tabcolsep,cells={c,m}}
\toprule
\SetCell[r=11]{c}{\textbf{Métricas de Base}}   & \Mtres {Todas as métricas que servem de base para o cálculo da vulnerabilidade, de forma preliminar.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                     & \SetCell[r=5]{c}{\textbf{Métricas de Explorabilidade}} & \Mdois {As métricas de explorabilidade refletem valores relativos ao componente afetado, bem como propriedades de uma vulnerabilidade que leve a cabo um ataque bem-sucedido.}                                &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\ \cline{3-4} 
                                     &                                              & \SetCell[r=1]{c,m}\textbf{Vetor de Ataque (AV)}         & \SetCell[r=1]{c,m}
Contexto pela qual a exploração da vulnerabilidade é possível - o valor será tanto maior quanto mais um atacante conseguir atingir (lógica e fisicamente) para explorar o componente vulnerável.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ \cline{3-4} 
                                     &                                              & \HH\textbf{Complexidade do Ataque (AC)}  & Condições para além do controlo do atacante que devem existir para explorar a vulnerabilidade.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ \cline{3-4} 
                                     &                                              & \textbf{Privilégios Necessários (PR)} & Nível de privilégios que um atacante deve possuir antes de explorar a vulnerabilidade com sucesso – quantos menos privilégios forem necessários, mais alta será a pontuação.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\ \cline{3-4} 
                                     &                                              & \textbf{Interação do Utilizador (UI)} & Captura a necessidade de um utilizador humano, diferente do atacante, participar no comprometimento bem-sucedido do componente vulnerável                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                     & \textbf{Contexto (S)}                                 & \Mdois {Captura se uma vulnerabilidade num componente vulnerável afeta os recursos noutros componentes para além do seu contexto de segurança.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                     & \SetCell[r=4]{c}{\textbf{Métricas de Impacto}}         & \Mdois {Capturam os efeitos de uma vulnerabilidade explorada com sucesso no componente que sofre o pior resultado que está mais direta e previsivelmente associado ao ataque.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\ \cline{3-4} 
                                     &                                              & \HH\textbf{Confidencialidade (C)}        & Mede o impacto sobre a confidencialidade dos recursos de informação geridos por um componente de software graças a uma vulnerabilidade explorada com sucesso – a classificação é maior quando a perda para o componente afetado é maior.                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \cline{3-4} 
                                     &                                              & \textbf{Integridade (I)}              & Mede o impacto na integridade de uma vulnerabilidade explorada com sucesso – a classificação é maior quando a consequência para o componente afetado é maior.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \cline{3-4} 
                                     &                                              & \HH\textbf{Disponibilidade (A)}          & Mede o impacto na disponibilidade do componente afetado resultante de uma vulnerabilidade explorada com sucesso. Como a disponibilidade se refere à acessibilidade dos recursos de informação, os ataques que consomem largura de banda da rede, ciclos do processador ou espaço em disco impactam a disponibilidade do componente afetado – a classificação é maior quando a consequência para o componente impactado é maior. \\ \hline
\SetCell[r=4]{c}{\textbf{Métricas Temporais}}  & \Mtres {As métricas temporais medem o estado atual das técnicas de exploração ou disponibilidade de código, a existência de \textit{patches} ou uma solução de recurso (comumente designado em inglês por \textit{workaround}), ou a certeza da descrição da vulnerabilidade}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                     & \textbf{Exploração da Maturidade do Código (E)}       & \Mdois {Mede a probabilidade de a vulnerabilidade ser atacada e é normalmente baseada no estado atual das técnicas de exploração, disponibilidade de código de exploração ou exploração ativa \textit{in-the-wild}.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                     & \textbf{Nível de Remediação (RL)}                     & \Mdois {É um fator importante para a priorização - quanto menos oficial EXPLICAR O QUE É OFICIAL?! e permanente for uma correção, maior será a pontuação de uma vulnerabilidade.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                     & \textbf{Confiança no Reporte (RC)}                    & \Mdois {Mede o grau de confiança na existência da vulnerabilidade e na credibilidade dos detalhes técnicos conhecidos - quanto mais uma vulnerabilidade é validada pelo fornecedor ou outras fontes confiáveis, maior será a pontuação.}                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
\SetCell[r=3]{c}{\textbf{Métricas Ambientais}} & \Mtres {As métricas ambientais permitem a personalização da pontuação do CVSS, dependendo da importância do ativo de TI afetado para a organização de um utilizador, medida em termos de controlos de segurança complementares e/ou alternativos implementados, confidencialidade, integridade e disponibilidade.}                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \cline{2-4}
                                     & \textbf{Requisitos de Segurança (CR, IR, AR)}         & \Mdois {Permitem que o analista personalize a pontuação CVSS, dependendo da importância do ativo de TI afetado para a organização de um utilizador, medida em termos de confidencialidade, integridade ou disponibilidade - cada requisito de segurança tem três valores possíveis: Baixo, Médio ou Alto.}                                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-4}
                                     & \textbf{Métricas de Base Modificadas}                 & \Mdois {Permitem que o analista substitua as métricas básicas individuais com base em características específicas do ambiente de um utilizador; delas fazem parte a Modified Attack Vector (MAV), Modified Attack Complexity (MAC), Modified Privileges Required (MPR), Modified User Interaction (MUI), Modified Scope (MS), Modified Confidentiality (MC), Modified Integrity (MI) ou Modified Availability (MA).}                                \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]